# The class that implements the interface doesn't work because "Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method...". What is the mistake?

Tags: java, interface, interface-implementation

There is an [example of "Implementing an Interface"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) in Java tutorial. I have repeated this example but it doesn't work. NetBeans shows the mistake on te left of `RectanglePlus` class declaration. And mistake is:

> rectangleplus.RectanglePlus is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method isLargerThan(rectangleplus.Relatable) in
>   rectangleplus.Relatable

I did the same as written in tutorial. Why it shows the mistake? Here is my implementation of the project.

1. The name of the project is `RectanglePlus`.
2. The name of the package is `rectangleplus`.

1st file in the project is Interface `Relatable`:

```
package rectangleplus;

public interface Relatable {
   int isLarger(Relatable other);   
}
```

2nd file in the project is Main Class `RectanglePlus` with helper class `Point`:

```
package rectangleplus;

public class RectanglePlus implements Relatable {

    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public Point origin;

    // four constructors
    public RectanglePlus() {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
    }
    public RectanglePlus(Point p) {
        origin = p;
    }
    public RectanglePlus(int w, int h) {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    public RectanglePlus(Point p, int w, int h) {
        origin = p;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    // a method for moving the rectangle
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        origin.x = x;
        origin.y = y;
    }

    // a method for computing
    // the area of the rectangle
    public int getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    // a method required to implement
    // the Relatable interface
    public int isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
        RectanglePlus otherRect 
            = (RectanglePlus)other;
        if (this.getArea() < otherRect.getArea())
            return -1;
        else if (this.getArea() > otherRect.getArea())
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;               
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TODO code application logic here
   }
}

class Point {
   int top;
   int left;
   int x;
   int y;

   public Point(int t, int l) {
      top = t;
      left = l;
   }
}
```

Why there is nothing said about abstraction in the tutorial example? Should the tutorial example work without mitakes?

Thank you.

Comment: just a comment: don't let a `is`XYZ method return an `int` value. `is`-methods should return `boolean`s. if you want to return an `int`, call your method `compare`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interface, you declare the method `isLarger` but in the class you declare `isLargerThan` Change one to the other name and it will go fine.

Answer (score 3):

You're not correctly implementing the `isLarger()` method in the `Relatable` interface. Rename the `isLargerThan(Relatable other)` method so it looks like this:

```
@Override
int isLarger(Relatable other) {
}
```

It's a good idea to use the `@Override` annotation, it allows you to catch errors like the one in the question.